# Process memory stacking when drawing bitmap

Tags: vb.net, memory, bitmap

I have a small application that draws pressure vessels. its not much, just drawing rectangles and arcs.

The user provides input and presses a button to generate the drawing.

But if you keep jamming the button, the process memory increases with each button press. How can I avoid this?

Is the image not disposed by placing a new one in to the picture box?

```
Private Sub btnRedraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRedraw.Click
```

Dim oBlackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, oBitmapHeight / 1000)

```
    If Not pbVessel.Image Is Nothing Then
        pbVessel.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    Dim oImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Convert.ToInt16(oBitmapWidth), Convert.ToInt16(oBitmapHeight))
    Dim oGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(oImage)

    ' Le fancy drawing code

    pbVessel.Image = oImage
End Sub
```

Edit: I dispose the picturebox image if the image is not nothing, the problem is still persistent.

Comment: It'll probably get garbage collected eventually, but you don't need to create a new bitmap each time. Just clear the one you have.

Comment: Then I will need to resize the bitmap when the user presses the button. Is there a way to resize a bitmap without creating a new one? I only find samples that create a new bitmap.

Comment: You're not disposing of any of the objects you create: `Bitmap`, `Graphics object` and `Pen`. Plus, based on the method you're using, you need to also dispose of the Image assigned to PictureBox before assigning a new one.

Comment: That being said, is this Bitmap (`oImage`) changing, at some point, so that you need to re-paint a new one for each button click? Why are you also re-setting the PictureBox properties each time?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, the image is changing based on the user input. I changed the code a bit, I dispose the image from the picture box and removed the picturebox property setting. Result is the same. The Memory increases 15MB on a redraw of the image on a medium size image.

Comment: You have to dispose of **all** the objects **you** create. See the previous comments. You should also show what's being done in the *Le fancy drawing code* part. Maybe you're using Brushes there.